# fluent validation validating a list of generated text boxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, fluentvalidation

I have set of textboxes on my form which are generated in a foeach like so:

View:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.TransomeList.Count; i++)
                        {
                            ItemDrops tranItem = Model.TransomeList.ElementAt(i);
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.Label(tranItem.ItemName.ToString(), new { @class = "col-sm-6 control-label" })

                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TransomeList[i].ItemPossInfo, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TransomeList[i].ItemName)
                                </div>
                            </div>                                
                        }
```

I'm using fluent validation and want to make sure each text box is required (ideally stating which text box too in the error message)

In my Validator class I have:

```
RuleFor(x => x.TransomeList).SetCollectionValidator(new TransDropValidator());
```

with:

```
 public class TransDropValidator : AbstractValidator<ItemDrops>
{
    public TransDropValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.ItemPossInfo)
            .NotNull().WithMessage("Transom position required{O}", x => x.ItemPossInfo);
    }
}
```

However this is not validating anything...what do i need to do?

Thanks

Comment: Are you other fluent validator validators are working or this is the only one? Have you set up correctly the MVC integration as described here: http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc? Because your code should just work (at least the server side validation part the because the `SetCollectionValidator` does not support client side validation...)

Comment: @nemesv other validation works but this is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You also need the

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor()
```

I assume you are doing server side validation. If not then futher work is need on your validator and you need to generate the JavaScript component.

Comment: I just want it to appear in validation summary and highlight text box

Comment: OK, now I see what the problem is. I solved something similar but will need to look it up. Do you intend to use server or client side validation.

Comment: ideally both, but server will be enough for now